# How to Count Directories in iOS Documents Directory

Tags: swift, nsfilemanager

I'm trying to count the number of directories in the iOS Documents Directory of my app using the following swift code:

```
    let manager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let path: NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Documents")
    var array = manager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(path, error: nil)
    let count = array?.count
```

My Documents directory currently contains one directory but when I run this code, 'count' returns nil every time. Why is this?

Comment: That most probably means that `array` is already `nil`. You should *use* the `error` parameter of `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath()`, check the return value and print the error. – Have you checked if `path` contains what you expect?

Comment: I'd never used the error pointer before but I gave it a shot and it gave me: "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory". Does that suggest that it couldn't find the 'Documents' directory, or that it was empty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method to find the Documents directory is wrong, `NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath` gives the path to the application bundle.

There is a dedicated function for this purpose:

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
```

And then you should use the error parameter and check the return value when
retrieving the directory contents:

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
var error : NSError?
if let files = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(documentsPath, error: &error) {
    let count = files.count
    // ...
} else {
    println("Could not get contents of directory: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Credit to Martin R. for the original answer! Here is a Swift 3 version incase anyone needs it...

**Swift 3**

```
    func countFilesInDocumentsDirectory() {

        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) [0] as String

        do {
            let files = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: documentsPath)
            print("File count = \(files.count)")
            for i in 0...files.count-1 {
                print("FILE: \n\(files[i])")
            }
        } catch {
            //...
        }
    }
```